# Autoboot on gumtix

Tags: autologin, gumstix

I am trying to get my gumstix computer to automatically login so that I can run a program that reboots it and the scps over a file. My problem is that I try to follow the instructions here: [Autologin](http://wiki.gumstix.org/index.php?title=AutoLogin)
But when I try and compile it I get this error: 'memset' was not declared in this scope
Has anyone figured out how to fix this or is there an easier way to approach this problem

-Thanks

Comment: Update: I got it working by adding #include <string.h> But now I have a new problem. I changed the line in the inittab that the gumstix page told me to. And now my gumstix tries to boot and doesn't. It stops at "INIT: Id "S" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes" ANy clues on how to fix/get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Your login program is exiting instead of spawning a successful login process.